# Figure out the IP Address of a desktop application

Tags: ip-address

If I am running a desktop application or program how would I be able to see what server I am connected to, more specifically the Ip address of that server. Is this even achievable?

For example, I am playing a game such as Starcraft. I have to be connected to some server to play this game. I would just like to figure out the ip of Starcraft's game server.

Comment: How did you connect to a server without knowing its address in one form or another? Your question lacks a lot of details. I would point you to Internet sockets, but I am beginning to think you want a list of all active TCP connections for a single process, which is highly platform specific.

Comment: I made an example in my edit, hopefully this clarifies what I am asking.

Comment: Well **wireshark** sounds the program you need. However, you have to track the packets there to locate it.